# Joining a Microsoft SQL Server and SQLite table

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I have a Microsoft SQL Server database as well as a database in SQLite. Now I am trying to join my SQLite with the table in Microsoft SQL Server database. Can anybody tell me how I can join the tables in SQLite with the Microsoft SQL Server tables? Is it possible at all?

Comment: There is no database software named "SQL".

Comment: What do you mean with "SQL database"? **All** relational databases are "SQL databases" because all use SQL as their query language - including SQLite. So your question doesn't really make sense

Comment: SmartyPants can you join a SQL table with a table in SQLite?

Comment: theoretically...it is possible, though it has never been done before

Comment: **Every** table in SQLite is a "SQL table". Your question doesn't make sense. What exactly do you mean with "SQL table"? Basically the answer is: yes, it's possible to join two "SQL tables" in SQLite.

Comment: Since I am missing "Server" after my SQL, you got confused. Check if I am making more sense now:
Can we Join a SQL Server table with a SQLite table?

Comment: @AminAkhtar Do you mean *Microsoft* SQL Server? Then please edit your question (and the title) accordingly.  As to your question: It not possible to perform joins between different databases, let alone such different databases as MS SQL and SQLite.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.